# Hide out of stock products in home page not in the catalog

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I know how to hide the products from catalog since Woocommerce settings but i need to hide out of stock products in some pages, i have this code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'code_hide_out_of_stock_in_home' );
function code_hide_out_of_stock_in_home( $query ) {
    if( is_page( array( 5576, 6489, 2 ) ) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' ); 
        $query->set( 'meta_value', 'instock' );
    }
}
```

It works very well but for one reason in the pages that i apply the code my header menu disappears and i don't know why. I already know that the problem is in the code because when i hide the code my header menu appears again.

I need that the out of stock products don't appear in the specific pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually multiple queries running on each page. One of them is the query that fetches the menu items. With your custom `pre_get_posts` action you essentialy told WordPress to check whether those header menu items have `instock` value for `_stock_status` meta keys (and of course they don't).

You should check whether the query is associated with `product` post type and only set your query parameters if it is:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'code_hide_out_of_stock_in_home' );
function code_hide_out_of_stock_in_home( $query ) {

    // Only apply for 'product' post_type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product' ) {

        // Only on these page IDs
        if( is_page( array( 5576, 6489, 2 ) ) ) {
            $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' ); 
            $query->set( 'meta_value', 'instock' );
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you display those products using `[products]` shortcode, a better approach would be to use the `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` filter, not the `pre_get_posts` action. Check [this question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966402/display-only-in-stock-products-in-woocommerce-recent-products-shortcode) for more info.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, it works very well for me, i was looking for a solution for a while but you was the only one that give me an actual solution